# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

can anyone suggest the code to store multiple selected values from listbox to database in asp.net c#

```
 string day = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
 //DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = 
                Convert.ToDateTime(day.ToString())).DayOfWeek.ToString();
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
     DateTime dtd = Convert.ToDateTime(day).Date;
     dtd = dtd.AddDays(7);
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dtd;
     DateTime date = dtd;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i ].Cells[1].Value = 
                   (Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString())).DayOfWeek.ToString();
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
Parameter name: index.
```

Comment: The error seams pretty clear. You try accessing non existing index in  a collection.

Comment: How many rows and columns are there?

Comment: Can you check your datagrid view for how many rows and cells it is having? you can use debugger. Maybe the datagridview1 does not have any rows. The code is getting bumped in the first line only

Comment: and columns? also: what line throws the exception?

Comment: columns 3 and error on ' dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dtd'

Comment: When you access with `[...]`, as in `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`, the number ("index") must be between 0 and the number of items in the collection minus one. Your exception will tell you what line and what indexer gave the error. Check for example if `i == 9` is too high.

Comment: Where do you populate dataGridView1.Rows?

Comment: where is the datagridview getting the datafrom? does it have a `DataSource`? if so: what is the data source? Is it a `DataTable`? a `List<T>` ? a `BindingList<T>`? a `BindingSource`? or...?

Comment: @Archit and what is `theTable.Rows.Count` and `theTable.Columns.Count`?

Comment: Do you explicitly need the rows 1 to 9 or can you just `foreach` over every row in `dataGridView1`

Comment: btw, showing the first few lines of the stacktrace would probably make it easier for us to infer exactly where the wheel is falling off

Comment: @Marc Gravell Table.Rows.Count=10 and Table.Columns.Count=3

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that for the size of X, index is 0 to (x-1).

So maybe you want to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
```

Or use `i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count()` as your loop stopper condition statement instead of i<9 .

Comment: The OP indicates there are 10 rows; the 1/0 is almost certainly an error (ignoring the first row), but the < 10 looks correct

Comment: In this answer `i == 8` will be the last iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: I dont really know the size of the collection, so we can't tell if its really 9 or 10. I just wanted to point a possible error.

Comment: @Freelancer nothing, this is exactly the same, hence why I commented on both of them. I voted on neither. I do not believe this answer addresses the problem either. If you mean "why is this +1 when my identical answer was -2?", then: I don't know the answer to that either.

Comment: @MarcGravell Aprt from loop stopping issue, both of the answers are right.

Comment: @Freelancer no, both are equally wrong. All you are doing is processing an extra row (note that actually the OP processes row 0 explicitly before the loop). Even if that 0th row works fine, we should still expect the same error to occur when we are processing whatever row we were processing last time.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start accessing to rows or cells you should create one!!!
I Hope this code will help you

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("date", "Date");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("day", "Day");

        var day = DateTime.Now;
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        cell.Value = (Convert.ToDateTime(day.ToString())).DayOfWeek.ToString();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DateTime dtd = Convert.ToDateTime(day).Date;
            dtd = dtd.AddDays(7);
            row = new DataGridViewRow();
            cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            cell.Value = dtd.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            DateTime date = dtd;
            cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            cell.Value = (Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString())).DayOfWeek.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure dataGridView visible property is "visible=true"